# RSAUtils Decryption , Converting data to it's original value - Swift

Tags: swift, encryption, swift3, base64, nsdata

i am trying to encrypt and decrypt a string using RSAUtils swift library, i am having a problem returning the decrypted text to it's original value . this is the code:

```
let PUBLIC_KEY = "MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAJh+/sdLdlVVcM5V5/j/RbwM8SL++Sc3dMqMK1nP73XYKhvO63bxPkWwaY0kwcUU40+QducwjueVOzcPFvHf+fECAwEAAQ=="    
let sampleText:String = "WHATS UP"    
let encrypted:Data? = RSAUtils.encryptWithRSAPublicKey(sampleText.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, pubkeyBase64: PUBLIC_KEY, keychainTag: "12345")! 
let decrypted:Data? = RSAUtils.decryptWithRSAPublicKey(encrypted!, pubkeyBase64: PUBLIC_KEY, keychainTag: "12345") 
let encryptedDataText = encrypted!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions())  
let decryptedDataText = decrypted!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions())
```

I tried to convert the decrypted data to string using this code:

```
if let string = String(data: decrypted! , encoding: .utf16) {
    print(string)
} else {
    print("not a valid UTF-16 sequence")
}
```

But it prints "㺸ꉄ꤈꽹㲞㏯荘뼵鉉큅령嬰ꢤẲ毪쌶⏤ᱼ埡佒�ࡊᩏ⧚㨈؍੯屍" I also tried to decode the base64 value using :

```
let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: decryptedDataText)!
let decodedString = String(data: decodedData, encoding: .utf8)!
print(decodedString)
```

It causes an error

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an O

probably the text is not a valid base64 string.

How can i convert the decrypted data to it's original value.

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely the decryption failed and that is why the result is not  valid UTF-8. Add to the question the value of `decrypted` and `decodedData` (in hex).

Comment: In the GitHub repository of `RSAUtils` there's a project containing an example. Why don't you follow that?

Comment: @vadian That's what i did , and the result was the same.